# How to assign value to a copy object without effect original object

Tags: c#, class, oop, object

I create 3 objects but when I change one object property among 3 object all of it is changed too.
so how can I change object property without effect other objects?

```
public DetachForm(MessageViewModel messageViewModel)
{            
    a = new MessageViewModel();
    a = messageViewModel;
    var b = new MessageModel();
    b = a.CurrentMessage;
    //property name in messageViewModel,a and b object equal to "Old"
     b.Name = "New";
   //property name in messageViewModel,a and b object equal to "New"
}
```

Comment: Use DeepCloning to copy objects and break reference.

Comment: @KarthikAMR - not the problem in this case as it is in any case a new object

Comment: It seems you need to clone the object, try ICloneable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=netframework-4.7.1. As b=a is changing the pointer to messageViewModel you are passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look closely at what is actually going on.

```
public DetachForm(MessageViewModel messageViewModel)  //  <--- first object in memory
{            
    a = new MessageViewModel();  //  <--- create a new object in memory
    a = messageViewModel;  // <--- change the reference a to reference the messageViewModel
    var b = new MessageViewModel();  //  <--- create a new third object in memory
    b = a;  //  <--- change b to reference the same object as a

    a.id=1;  // At this point messageViewModel, a, b - all reference the same object in memory
}
```

Therefore when you get to the line of `a.id = 1` you actually change the one object in memory that all of these three references are referencing.

Also once you execute the second line of the function then the object you just created has no reference referencing it and the GC will collect that memory. Same applies to forth line of function.

To change a property of `b` without changing `messageViewMovel` (as these are reference types and in any case you are creating a new instance):

```
var b = new MessageViewModel();
b.id = 1; // when debugging see that messageViewModel was not changed
```

---

Even in your update you have the same problems. The following code is equivalent to what you wrote in your update:

```
a = messageViewModel;
var b = a.CurrentMessage;
b.Name = "New";
```

So as you see it doesn't matter you created new instances if then you override them with the "old" one. So when you change `b.Name` you actually access the same object in memory as `a.CurrentMessage.Name`.

If you want to duplicate all the `MessageViewModel` then I recommend having a look at `IClonable` (or have copy constructors). If your class will implement the interface then you can:

```
var copy = messageViewModel.Clone();
copy.CurrentMessage.Name = "something"; // original will not change
```

Comment: Are there any way that I can change on object without effect other object?

Comment: @BenniTo - of course but the question is what are you actually trying to change? What is `a` and what `messageViewModel` - which do you want to change

Comment: if I want to change property in object b without effect a and messageViewModel object, so how can I do with that?

Comment: So how about changing property object in inside other object?

Comment: @BenniTo - please explain what you are actually trying to do. You are missing some important C# basics. If you do `c = new ...` and then `c = something` then it doesn't matter you did the `new`...

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour comes from the way C# handles your object references. When you do:

```
b = a;
```

You say that *b* should reference the same object as *a*. You are modifying the same object, no matter if you use the a or b reference.